# Animation In Wp7

Tags: c#

I Am making an Live Candle app for windows phone..i want to change the orientation of frames when the orientation of phone is changed..i am not able to do so..i am using the following code:-

```
namespace sdkSimpleMotionCS
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    Motion motion;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if the Motion API is supported on the device.
        if (!Motion.IsSupported)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the Motion API is not supported on this device.");
            return;
        }

        // If the Motion object is null, initialize it and add a CurrentValueChanged
        // event handler.
        if (motion == null)
        {
            motion = new Motion();
            motion.TimeBetweenUpdates = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            motion.CurrentValueChanged += new EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<MotionReading>>(motion_CurrentValueChanged);
        }

        // Try to start the Motion API.
        try
        {
            motion.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("unable to start the Motion API.");
        }
    }

    void motion_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<MotionReading> e)
    {
        // This event arrives on a background thread. Use BeginInvoke to call
        // CurrentValueChanged on the UI thread.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => CurrentValueChanged(e.SensorReading));
    }
    private void CurrentValueChanged(MotionReading e)
    {
        if (motion.IsDataValid)
        {
            // Show the numeric values for attitude
            yawTextBlock.Text = "YAW: " + MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Yaw).ToString("0") + "°";
            pitchTextBlock.Text = "PITCH: " + MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Pitch).ToString("0") + "°";
            rollTextBlock.Text = "ROLL: " + MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Roll).ToString("0") + "°";

            // Set the Angle of the triangle RenderTransforms to the attitude of the device
            ((RotateTransform)yawtriangle.RenderTransform).Angle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Yaw);
            ((RotateTransform)pitchtriangle.RenderTransform).Angle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Pitch);
            ((RotateTransform)rolltriangle.RenderTransform).Angle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(e.Attitude.Roll);

            // Show the numeric values for acceleration
            xTextBlock.Text = "X: " + e.DeviceAcceleration.X.ToString("0.00");
            yTextBlock.Text = "Y: " + e.DeviceAcceleration.Y.ToString("0.00");
            zTextBlock.Text = "Z: " + e.DeviceAcceleration.Z.ToString("0.00");

            // Show the acceleration values graphically
            xLine.X2 = xLine.X1 + e.DeviceAcceleration.X * 100;
            yLine.Y2 = yLine.Y1 - e.DeviceAcceleration.Y * 100;
            zLine.X2 = zLine.X1 - e.DeviceAcceleration.Z * 50;
            zLine.Y2 = zLine.Y1 + e.DeviceAcceleration.Z * 50;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using motion concept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [handle OrientationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event in Page or better use this class instead of default PhoneApplicationFrame  [Code to animate and fade Windows Phone orientation changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/28/this-one-s-for-you-gregor-mendel-code-to-animate-and-fade-windows-phone-orientation-changes-now-supports-a-new-mode-hybrid.aspx)